# How do I change the value of the string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, replace, boolean

Playing around in C# trying to make a name input system but none of the code within my while loop affects the code outside it. First part of the code works perfectly but when entering the loop I cant manage to change any of the values which effectively traps me within it. pls help.

```
class name
        {
            public static string nameTag;
        }
        class oK
        {
            public static string nameBool;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Whats your Name?");
            string nameTag = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(nameTag + ", is that correct?");
            string nameBool = Console.ReadLine();

            if(nameBool=="no")
            {
                
                while (nameBool=="no")
                {
                    name.nameTag = String.Empty;
                    name.nameTag = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(nameTag + ", is that correct?");
                    oK.nameBool = String.Empty;
                    oK.nameBool = Console.ReadLine();

                }
}
}
```

Comment: You have `nameTag` and `name.nameTag` and you're mixing them up. Also, you don't really seem to understand the use of `static`. Read about that as well. A string called `nameBool` indicates that you're uncertain on how to store things and you don't separate the concepts of user input versus storing business data. The string is the user input. After comparing it to `"no"`, you want to store a boolean value for all the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code above, you have static classes defined when you could just be using a variable.

Here is some of your code tidied up (Notice `nameTag` and `nameBool` are only defined once):

```cs
public class Example
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Whats your Name?");
        string nameTag = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(nameTag + ", is that correct?");
        string nameBool = Console.ReadLine();

        while (nameBool == "no")
        {
            nameTag = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(nameTag + ", is that correct?");
            nameBool = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the `if` is unnecessary, because `while` already checks it.

Comment: Ah true, added an edit to clean it up.